# Firestore error within React: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

The following is my function in which I am trying to filter notes from my Firestore collection by user.uid:

```
const fetchPost = async () => {
    const queryConstraints = []
    if (user.uid != null) queryConstraints.push(where('userID', '==', user.uid))
    if (user.email != null) queryConstraints.push(where('userEmail', '==', 

user.email))
        const q = query(collection(db, 'notes'), ...queryConstraints)
        await getDocs(collection(q))
            .then((querySnapshot)=>{              
                const newData = querySnapshot.docs
                    .map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id }));
                setNotes(newData);                
                console.log(notes, newData);
            })
    }
```

Yet, when I try and run this code in the browser, regardless if it is Chrome, Safari, Firefox, I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'uid')
> at fetchPost (NoteList.js:66:1)

I am not sure how to fix this error, or really the right question to ask over how ask over why this this is happening.

Previously, I was using the following function:

```
const fetchPost = async () => {
        await getDocs(collection(db, "notes"))
            .where('userEmail', '==', user.email)
            .then((querySnapshot)=>{              
                const newData = querySnapshot.docs
                    .map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id }));
                setNotes(newData);                
                console.log(notes, newData);
            })
    }
```

I was getting the same error previously stated, but at least with this function, if I made any change to user.uid, React's hot reload would refresh the page, and it would bring in the queried data in the console, yet when I F5 the page, the data was not showing with the error message listed above.

Also, when I use the query builder in Firestore with the same parameters, I am able to pull the data I want to display, it is just not pulling/displaying as wanted in my react app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')` Apparently, `user` in `if (user.uid != null)` is null. Can you show us where `user` is defined?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your `user` is `null`.

1. Try to print value of `user` before accessing `id`.  You'll know the value of user
2. Try to wrap your `user.id` with `if(user) user.id`.  This should remove your erros

Comment: I will try this out, but I looking at this and thinking about it, this would be the clearest answer to fixing my issue. Thanks!